# Что такое \sql\query в Управлении общими ресурсами и хранилищами

Tags: sql, windows, sql-server, windows-server

Windows Server 2012. MSSQL 2014
В управлении общими ресурсами и хранилищами, в Управлении открытыми файлами висят файлы `\sql\query`, открытые из под пользователя. Что это за SQL запрос?

Если данный "файл" открыт от пользователя, то получается, что проходит авторизация на уровне ОС, а не SQL?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Соединение с SqlServer, по-видимому, происходит с использованием _named pipe_, и `\sql\query` - имя канала.

Comment: Named Pipe включены. А данный канал может влиять на подключение к данному серверу по SMB? То есть,от удаленного клиента создается named pipe на сервере, и этот же клиент подключается по файловой шаре из под другого пользователя и ловит ошибку  множественного подключения. Это   может как-то влиять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL server настроен на прослушивание \sql\query
в настройках баз поглядите галочку Enable Named Pipes and TCP/IP Connections, и нужна ли она